# How to store values from request body from post http request in to variables

Tags: jmeter

1. Send post http request with random values (never know which value will pass each time)
2. once post request I need to store all the values from request body in to variables

[image]

Note: I need to store all the values from description to bvalue into variables where I need to use in multiple places.

I have tried JSR223 post processed with below code but getting null values:

```
def parameters = sampler.getArguments().argumentsAsMap

  vars.put('description', parameters.get('description[0]'))
  vars.put('episodeTypeId', parameters.get('episodeTypeId[0]'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean `description` - you're saving it into `${randomID}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html).

Other variables are available already.

If you want to save variable values as new variables with argument names, i.e. `id`, `description`, `episodeTypeId`, `duration`, etc. you can amend your code like:

```
def parameters = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue())

parameters.entrySet().each { entry ->
    vars.put(entry.key, entry.value as String)
}
```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, 

You are obsolutely correct. I wanted store / save values as new variables.

can you please explain me as a fresher where should I add the above code? if you can take once example e.g take durarion and how to store in new variable.

Comment: It will automatically convert all the attributes into the relevant JMeter Variables. So if you put the code into JSR223 PostProcessor you will be able to access the duration as `${duration}` where required

Comment: Yes, it worked for me and I'm able to get values. Thanks Dmitri...